# Matrix multiplication across blocks - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have 2 Matrices like:

```
A = [1 2;
     3 4;
     5 6];
```

and

```
B = [1 1 1;
     2 2 2;
     3 3 3;
     4 4 4;
     5 5 5;
     6 6 6];
```

what I wanna do is multiple the `i`th row of `A` with the `2*(i-1)+1` to `2*i` rows of  in `B`, like:

```
[1 2]*[1 1 1;2 2 2]
```

and combine the results together. The size of the result matrix will be 3X3. I know of course I can do a for loop to get my result. But my `A` and `B` are actually very large, so for loop costs too much time.

Can someone give me any advice on how to do this without for loop? I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Please make an attempt and post your code. This isn't a code writing service but the community can help you along if you can put in some work too.

Comment: Hi, Fencer04, I am not asking others to write code for me. I just think maybe someone has done similar work and can give me some advice.  Maybe you have some suggestions?

Comment: you can use `reshape` and then use a `bsxfun` to parallel the process.

Comment: Thank you very much, @GameOfThrows ! Your advice is really good, I have seperated A in columns and seperated B in odd row matrix and even row matrix, and use like bsxfun(@times, B_odd, A(:,1)), finally assemble them together. It was really great. For my case with a Matrix of  size 2601X2, the calculation times reduced from 0.43s to 0.0041s, really amazing !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) could be used after reshaping `B`, like so -

```
squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,reshape(B,size(A,2),[],size(B,2)),A.'),1))
```

Comment: Nice answer, i was just about to click *send* with more or less the same.

Comment: great! thanks too, really a lot learned. I'm thinking about giving up for loop forever in matlab!

Comment: @JayWang That's the way to do it!! ;)